# Help with queue and singly linked lists?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

Im currently working on trying to understand Lists, Stacks, and Queues in C++.  Im reviewing for my test and came across a question asking to `"efficiently implement a queue class using a singly linked list, with no header or tail nodes."`

Im kind of stumped, does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: Queues are often implemented using circular buffers. How would you create a circle with a singly linked list?

Comment: Isn't that the next level of complexity, using a more efficient memory allocation scheme than a singly linked list?

Comment: @Anders I agree his use of "circular buffer" is confusing in this context, but what he means is a very good hint - though it works better with doubly-linked lists

Comment: I simply mean that the "circle" concept of a queue can also be applied to a singly linked list. @rlc: You don't need a doubly linked list. You can implement a queue with O(1) push and pop using just singly linked lists.

Comment: ok, so in a Queue whenever the front or back gets to the end of the array it wraps around to the beginning, which is the "circle" you are talking about. Now how would this differ if there were no header or tail nodes?

Comment: @tehman: The list needs need to be a circle i.e. the next pointer on the last node should point to the first node (so there's no head or tail). You'll still need to keep track of where you are in the circle, but there are no explicit head and tail nodes like in a normal list.

Comment: I don't see why one would ever use a ring if the underlying implementation is a linked list (and not a fixed-size buffer).  What's the benefit?

Comment: @Peter Alexander: ahhh I get it! Thank you sir

Comment: @Hostile Fork: Well, the obvious benefit of using a linked list instead of a fixed-size buffer is that the list isn't fixed size :)

Comment: @Peter: I think you might have missed @Hostile Fork's point. If you are using a link list for this, the size can grow as needed. Why, in this case, would anyone change the implementation to be circular? About the only effects are A) the logic is now slightly more complex, and B) the size is now fixed.

Comment: @Peter: I meant benefits of making a ring structure vs. having head/tail nodes (when using a linked list).  I suppose you can save one pointer because you don't need to save both the head and the tail--you can save the tail only and get to the head in one step, still pushing and popping in O(1).  Dubious benefit, and costs you a dereference, but...

Comment: @Jonathan: Sorry, I don't understand what you are trying to say. The linked list is circular. What change are you talking about?

Comment: Because without the circular implementation when the queue appears to be full, the next enqueue would be in a nonexistent position. So whenever the front or back gets to the end of the array, it wraps around to the beginning.  (From my textbook)

Comment: @Peter: The answer I gave on implementing a queue with a singly linked list would not be circular. And it's size would not be fixed.

Comment: @Hostile Fork, @Joanthan Wood: Ok, I think I see what you are saying now. Yes, the benefits of making it circular vs non-circular are minimal, but it does save you a pointer in your queue structure (could be important if you have lots of empty queues).

Comment: @Peter: Right.  When I first read the question I thought it was nonsensical, because I didn't think of the ring.  Then I saw your answer and thought "ohhhh...silly me...of course you can make a queue without a head and tail."  Then I thought "wait a second, silly *exercise* - there's a reason I haven't seen this, it's pointless and will probably just make infinite loops more likely."  :-/

Comment: @Hostile Fork: I don't think it will make infinite loops more likely. After all, you can't iterate over a queue, you can only push or pop.

Comment: @Peter: It's greater code complexity, lack of intuitive debugging info...if someone implemented a linked list queue in this way to save one pointer for no reason I'd really question their judgment.  (Though I'll reiterate that the circular technique is an important CS concept when dealing with *fixed-size* buffers.)

Comment: @Hostile Fork: The code complexity isn't greater. The complexity of having both a head and tail link increases complexity because you have two pointers that could be null, instead of one.

Comment: @PeterAlexander ofcourse you can implement a O(1) queue with just a singly linked list - I just said it works better (i.e. is easier to do) with a doubly-linked list.

Answer (score 2):

You need to keep track of a pointer to the head and tail items in your list.

When you add a new item, point the tail item's next pointer to the new item, and then update the tail pointer.

To remove an item from the front of the list, just return the head item, and then update the head pointer.